# why is request.user.is_authenticated printing out false even when user is logged in and rendering template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am fairly new to Django and I use Django 4.2. I am building a website and I have run into this error. I have created my login function like this

```
def loginUsers(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']
        upass = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=upass)
        if user is not None:
                    login(request, user)
                    messages.success(request, 'Login successful')
                    time.sleep(2)
                    return redirect(reverse('index'))  
        else: 
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid user')
            return redirect(reverse('login'))
        
    return render(request, 'auth_pages/login.html', context)
```

But my logout function is not in this contact app views.py. It is in my index app views.py because the logout button in my template is in the navbar. Here it is:

```
def loadIndexPage(request):
    context = {}
    print(request.user.is_authenticated)
    return render(request, 'pages/index.html', context)


def logoutUser(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        logout(request)
        messages.success(request, 'You are logged out')
        return redirect(reverse('login'))
```

**The problem**

The problem is that the logout function is not logging out the user, it instead, is creating a csrftokenmiddleware in the browser search bar and when I print the
`request.user.is_authenticated` it prints `false`. In the template:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                    <p>Hey there user</p>
                
                {% else %}
                    <p>Not working</p>
{% endif %}
```

This is not working. It is only showing `Not working`.

I have tried to add a `@login_required` to the index function, but it kept redirecting to a page that I never created or added in the urls.py of the project.

I have gone through the documentation and did everything as stated but yet the issues persist.

I have tried to print out the `request.user.is_authenticated` and it is still printing false, even though the user is authenticated in the login function.

I checked the database and the column, `is_authenticated` is still FALSE.

I have two questions:

1. Is anything wrong with my code?
2. Should I have set the column `is_authenticated` to True?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely made a GET request, the form should be:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'logout' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">logout</button>
</form>
```

Likely the `method="POST"` is lacking, so it makes a GET request. Logging in/out should be done through a POST request, since this changes the state.

> I checked the database and the column, is_authenticated is still FALSE.

Normally the `User` model does *not* have a column named `is_authenticated`. This is not a database column, this is simply true for *all* `User`s. If the user is *not* logged in, `request.User` will return the `AnonymousUser` object, which has `is_authenticated` returning `False`.

Comment: So I should get rid of the is_authenticated column?

Comment: I used method='POST' not get.

Comment: @theocode: yes. Normally you just subclass the `AbstractUser` (although it is not clear to my why you want to make a custom user model in the first place). You can add extra columns, but `is_authenticated` isn't any of these.

Comment: @theocode: it has `csrftokenmiddleware` in the URL (you say yourself), that means your form makes a GET request.

Comment: i subclassed abstractbaseuser

Comment: I wonder how that's possible when the request.method is POST. Although I have an input tag in the form and it is set to type hidden. Could that be the issue?

Comment: @theocode: perhaps look at the developer console in the browser. If form values end up in the query part of the URL, that is how a GET request is made. In a POST request, the data is encoded in the header of the request.

Comment: Okay, I appreciate your help, the is_authenticated column was the problem.